# Easiest way to position iterator after the next line in a stream?

Tags: c++, parsing, stl

I feel like there should be a method or stl function for this, but I can't find anything. I'm writing a simple parser, if you're interested in my specific problem:

```
while (curChar << postFileStream)
    {
        switch (curChar)
        {
            case '\n' || '\r':
                break;
            case '#':
                skip_line(postFileStream)
        }
    }
```

Do I really have to make my own function to skip a line? I know it's a rather simple function, but I feel like c++ shouldn't require so much boilerplate these days; I must be missing something?

Answer (score 4):

```
postFileStream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

or

```
std::string s;
std::getline(postFileStream, s);
```

References:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streamsize/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/